# Add CSS Transform which goes endlessly and doesn't stop

Tags: css, animation, svg

I have an inline SVG which I want to animate and I am doing it like so:

```css
svg {
  animation: rotate 1s 0s infinite;
  stroke: black;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0turn);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="38" height="38" viewBox="0 0 38 38" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="#fff">
      <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
          <g transform="translate(1 1)" stroke-width="2">
              <circle stroke-opacity=".5" cx="18" cy="18" r="18"/>
              <path d="M36 18c0-9.94-8.06-18-18-18"></path>
          </g>
      </g>
</svg>
```

If you run the animation, at a point it will just stop running and start again.
Is there a way to make this go on smoothly?

Comment: What does "at some point" mean exactly?  How long?  And what browsers are you testing on?

Comment: "at some point" means at the point at which the animation ends. And I am using the latest version of Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default transition-timing-function is ease. That means the transition gets faster in its middle part. By changing it to linear the animation runs smoothly.

```
    svg {
        animation: rotate 1s 0s linear infinite;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
svg {
  animation: rotate 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="38" height="38" viewBox="0 0 38 38" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="#000">
      <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
          <g transform="translate(1 1)" stroke-width="2">
              <circle stroke-opacity=".5" cx="18" cy="18" r="18"/>
              <path d="M36 18c0-9.94-8.06-18-18-18"></path>
          </g>
      </g>
</svg>
```